# How to change encoding bitrate dynamically while streaming in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing c program to perform adaptive streaming but I could't change the "bitrate" property of x264enc element with g_object_set() function.How can i change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the git version of the gstreamer ugly plugin.Then `g_object_set()` function works fine.